# Remove decimal from float if it is equal to .0

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print a float value but if the value has no decimal (1.0, 2.0 etc, etc) I want to either remove the .0 part or convert it into an int so it removes the .0 anyway. Just for visual effect.

output:

> You started with: 1.0

Wanted output:

> You started with: 1

Comment: Specifically the second answer, and in this instance, try `print("You started with: {number:g}".format(number=1.0))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check if the number is a whole number or not

```
number = 1.5
if number.is_integer():
    number = int(number)

print(number)
```